# Horizontal scaling Json-Web-Token nodejs

Tags: node.js, json-web-token, horizontal-scaling

What is the proper way to scale JWT horizonatally in nodejs. I am using `RSA` to generate token. So each server would be able to decode tokens that were generated by itself. All the load balancing is stateless so there is no way to knowing which server generated the token. The current code that i am using is

```
helper['generateToken'] = (user)=>{
  return new Promise((fullfill,reject)=>{
    try{
      var cert = fs.readFileSync('pvt.key');
      var token = jwt.sign(user,process.env.SECRET);
      fullfill(token);
    }catch(ex){
      reject(new Error("Your token could not be generated"));
    }
  });
}
```

The `generateToken` function can run on any of the image and all of them have different private key. What could be the best way to scale with this.

> Just a side note i am running there instances on docker swarm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so each server would be able to decode tokens that were generated by itself. All the load balancing is stateless so **there is no way to knowing which server generated the token.**
>
> **...and all of them have different private key.**

Since a server could receive a token issued by the other server, and you can't distinguish the originator, **you need to use the same signing key.**

Alternatives

- **share the secret key** between instances using a shared folder or database (and consequently protect access to it)
- Use a **central authentication microservice** shared by all instances to sign tokens. If is being used a key pair, signature verification can be done locally en each instance. Problem: Also would need load balancing, but you can reduce the complexity of key sharing
- **Test all possible keys** (not very nice): use an assymetric key pair (RSA) and verify the token signature with all available public keys to check if any is correct

Comment: From point of view of `standard practices` is sharing private key with all servers a good idea ? I am new to token based auth usually wen't with session so not sure what would be the proper way to implement the same

Comment: The private key should be kept secure. Commont practices like virtualization, backups or cloning have always incur some kind of risk. It is possible to use hardware tokens (e.g HSM) to store the keys, that have their own replication & load balancing mechanism, but they are expensive... So consider the security of the whole hardware & software system when you plan the mechanism to share the key